# How to setup jenkins windows slave node to support msys2 mingw shell

Tags: jenkins, mingw32, msys2

I want to build a program with a jenkins windows 7 node. The program is build using cmake but in the configure stage cmake tells me that there is no g++ compiler. I think this error occurs due to the wrong shell but I don't know how to set the right shell. The documentation says that the first sh file on windows is executed but msys2 needs mingw32.exe as the correct shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways start MinGW shell:

1. Set env variable with `set MSYSTEM=mingw32` or `set MSYSTEM=mingw64`. Then start `msys2_shell.cmd` or `usr/bin/bash --login`.
2. Start `msys2_shell.cmd` with `-mingw32` or `-mingw64` arg.
3. Type in MSYS2 `source shell <name>` where  can be: `msys`, `mingw32`, `mingw64`.
4. Install `msys2-launcher-git` and run `mingw32.exe` or `mingw64.exe`

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming across this in the future: There's a much simpler solution: Just run the Jenkins build agent directly within MSYS2 (specifically within the MinGW64 (or MinGW32) terminal/shell). All commands issued by Jenkins will then run inside of MSYS2.

The only trick here is to add an environment variable to the node (in the Jenkins master instance Web UI) to add the MinGW64 (or MinGW32) binaries to the `PATH`. For this, add an environment variable named `PATH` with value `/mingw64/bin:$PATH`.

That's literally all it takes.

I've created a detailed guide: https://blog.insane.engineer/post/jenkins_msys2

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled but I got it right even on mixed/linux env. The original issue that I had was to automate x264 compilation on Windows (64 bits). What I did is the following

1. install MSYS2 64 bits  and use [pacman](http://www.msys2.org/) to install all the build environment (gcc, make, etc)
2. Create a BAT file in the C:\msys64 directory called msys-jenkins.bat

   ```
   rem convert path and script to unix format
   for /f %%a in ('c:\msys64\usr\bin\cygpath.exe %1') do set CMDFILE=%%a
   for /f %%a in ('c:\msys64\usr\bin\cygpath.exe %CD%') do set PWD=%%a

   rem setup visual studio 2015 env then launch msys2 64 bits
   set MSYSTEM=MINGW64
   set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit
   CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
   c:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -l -x -c "cd %PWD% ; %CMDFILE%"
   ```
3. Add a built step "Execute a shell script" that is

   ```
   #!C:\msys64\msys-jenkins.bat
   ./configure --enable-pic --enable-static --disable-swscale
   make
   make install
   ```

Et voilà !! This is definitely very tricky.

Comment: In my case, this does not work with  sh("""#!C:\msys64\msys-jenkins.bat .... """). jenkins 2.204

Answer (score 0):

As you rightfully noticed Jenkins will pickup the first sh executable it would find.
In fact it seems like it will choose the first `sh` `bash` or `cmd` available in `PATH` environment variable.

There are several ways to tell Jenkins which shell to use but I prefer the most easy and portable one. Inside node configuration in `Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > NodeName > Configure > Environment variables` add the environment variable `PATH` like so:

```
Name: PATH
Value: /c/msys64:/c/msys64/mingw64/bin:$PATH
```

This trick will work for all Linux macOS and Windows. But for msys2 specifically you should add another variable `MSYSTEM`

```
Name: MSYSTEM
Value: MINGW64
```

or value `MINGW32` depending on architecture. This is necessary for msys2 to correctly specify its own internal variables for the shell. [Here's some info on that.](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-introduction/#shells)

Don't forget to re-connect the node to make changes active.