# Execute commands in msy2 shell in VM and get output and return code

Tags: windows, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, virtualbox, msys2

**TL;DR:**
**How to execute commands in an msys2 shell in a Windows10 VM running in VirtualBox on a Linux host from a Jenkins pipeline and get output and return code?** At best I can run commands but not get output, return code, or exit on failure, so it's almost useless for a pipeline.

I need to build SW in Windows in a CI pipeline. For that I'm running a Win10 VM with Msys2 shell in VirtualBox on a Linux host which has a Jenkins agent. I'm having trouble running remote commands in the msys2 shell and getting the output. So e.g. I can run the build script but I can't see the output in real time and the bigger issue - if the build fails early the calling shell doesn't get the return code and it just keeps running until the pipeline stage times-out.

What I've tried:

- `vboxmanage guestcontrol`:

  - I've tried running the command via `msys2_shell.cmd` with every possible parameter. Either it doesn't work for some reason or weirder - the PATH and other stuff don't seem to be configured correctly. It's like `vboxmanage guestvontrol` always runs the command first via some Windows layer (`cmd.exe`?) and somehow the interaction with the `msys2` shell doesn't work correctly.
    `sh 'vboxmanage guestcontrol "${VM_NAME}" --username <name> --password <psd> run -- C:/msys64/msys2_shell.cmd -ucrt64 "ls -a > Z:/ls.log"` - this works. `Z:/` is a mounted dir and I can archive this file. But I don't see the output in the console. If the command would be `exit 1` the stage won't fail.
  - Besides that I've tried running the msys cmd via other shells like `cmd.exe`, `Windows Terminal` with `msys2` shell setup as the default shell, `powershell` - nothing works.
- `ssh`:
  I've tried setting an ssh server on the guest which will be up from startup.

  - I've tried using the `msys2 sshd` server solution  (https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Setting-up-SSHd/) but there are again weird issues with the PATH and stuff not being setup correctly.
    If I log in with ssh to the shell than it's ok **BUT when executing commands without logging in it's like it's not the msys2 shell**. It seems that Windows `OpenSsh` is also running the remote command first via a Windows shell before logging in to the msys shell sossh is only usable if you log in (useless for a pipeline!)
    Example:

    ```bash
    sshpass -p <psd> ssh -p 2222 -i .ssh/<private key> <username>@localhost ls
    ```

    results in `ls is not a command`
    BUT

    ```bash
    sshpass -p <psd> ssh -p 2222 -i .ssh/<private key> <username>@localhost
    ```

    logs me into the msys2 shell and then it works fine.
  - I've also tried running the Windows ssh server and setting a `DefaultShell` in the registry to use msys2 but that also doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There is [Quasi-MSYS2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2), which doesn't need a VM. It can either use Wine and/or cross-compile with Clang.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, but I need to try and find a solution on Windows OS.

Comment: I'm going to try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505300/how-to-setup-jenkins-windows-slave-node-to-support-msys2-mingw-shell It'll either require me to setup the node on the VM directly and keep the VM alive, or, run the pipeline on a Windows Machine directly.